# Resolve WCF Error: The EncryptedKey clause was not wrapped with the required encryption token 'System.IdentityModel.Tokens.X509SecurityToken'

Tags: c#, wcf, wcf-security, x509certificate2

I have a WCF client that is crashing with the error "The EncryptedKey clause was not wrapped with the required encryption token 'System.IdentityModel.Tokens.X509SecurityToken'." for every response.

I've looked around and [this blog post](http://webservices20.blogspot.com.au/2008/10/cryptic-wcf-error-messages-part-1-of-n.html) seems to indicate that the problem is with my certificate set up, but I'm not sure what I am doing wrong...

My client uses a custom binding with a MutualCertificateBindingElement for security, I am configuring the certificates in code as follows:

```
client.ClientCredentials.ServiceCertificate.Authentication.CertificateValidationMode = X509CertificateValidationMode.ChainTrust;
client.ClientCredentials.ServiceCertificate.SetDefaultCertificate
(
    StoreLocation.CurrentUser,
    StoreName.AddressBook,
    X509FindType.FindBySerialNumber,
    "[serial number 1]"
);

client.ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate.SetCertificate
(
    StoreLocation.CurrentUser,
    StoreName.My,
    X509FindType.FindBySerialNumber,
    "[serial number 2]"
);
```

The serial numbers match the values in the `<X509SerialNumber>` elements in both the request and the response messages.

One discrepancy I have noticed is the `<X509IssuerName>` elements in the request and the response are formatted differently:

```
Request:  CN=[CN], O=[O], L=[L], C=[C]
Response: C=[C],L=[L],O=[O],CN=[CN]
```

Is it possible this is causing the issue?

**UPDATE**

Turns out it was the certificate name formatting causing the issue. I managed to resolve it by replacing the cert names in the response with what WCF expects by using a custom encoder. Now I have this ugly hack, but it works so I'll live with it!

```
public override Message ReadMessage(ArraySegment<byte> buffer, BufferManager bufferManager, string contentType)
{   
    var msgContents = new byte[buffer.Count];
    Array.Copy(buffer.Array, buffer.Offset, msgContents, 0, msgContents.Length);
    bufferManager.ReturnBuffer(buffer.Array);
    var message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(msgContents);

    // Fix certificate issuer name formatting to match what WCF expects.
    message = message.Replace
    (
        "C=[C],L=[L],O=[O],CN=[CN]",
        "CN=[CN], O=[O], L=[L], C=[C]"
    );

    var stream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message));     
    return ReadMessage(stream, int.MaxValue);
}
```

Comment: please publish the request, response and config. you can also mail me if they are confidential

Comment: @YaronNaveh I have sent you an email rather than stick lots of code/xml in the question. If we are able to narrow down where the problem is I will update the question with the relevant snippets. Thanks!

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. How is that working for you when the certificate issuer name is now included in the message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issuer name order that you mentioned is most probably the issue. Since these names are not signed I suggest you write a custom encoder in your client that replaces the names in the response to be formatted as in the request.

Answer (score 0):

Besides obvious cert mismatch and barring miss-configuration... I have seen an issue trying to access private key. Check that client has appropriate permissions to the cert private key. If you right click on the cert in certmanager you should see AllTasks/Manage Private Keys. Add your client's process identity to  the list.

Comment: Good tip but this is not the issue in my case; I know the process can access the certs just fine since the request is successfully encrypted and signed, it's only the response that is causing problems.

Answer (score 0):

Also make sure that the certificate you are using is correct. I used self-signed certificate which was missing **Subject Key Identifier**.

[WCF : The EncryptedKey clause was not wrapped with the required encryption token 'System.IdentityModel.Tokens.X509SecurityToken'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46686785/wcf-the-encryptedkey-clause-was-not-wrapped-with-the-required-encryption-token)